# What is the connection between metric space and topological space?which come first?

Tags: algebraic-topology, metric-spaces

I'm trying to say that what is the hierarchical order for these two spaces and what is the definition of topological space?

Comment: Every metric space is a topological space.  Not every topological space is a metric space.  If you're interested in which came first historically, you might try [https://hsm.stackexchange.com/](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

A topological space is a pair (X, A) where X is a set and A is a topology.
A topology is a subset of $P(X) $ such that:

1. $\emptyset, X \in A$
2. If $\{U_i\} \subset A \Rightarrow \cup U_i \in A$
3. If $U, V\in A \Rightarrow U\cap V\in A$

$A$ is called the collection of open sets.

Now if you a a metric d, you can define a topology on X in a standard way.

So a metric space is automatically a topological space, but not every topogical space is a metric space: the trivial topology ($A=\{\emptyset, X\} $) is non metric on $X=\mathbb{R} $.

Answer (score 0):

As NaveMozza says above, every **metric** induces a **topology**: given a metric space $(X,d)$, we get a topology $\tau_d$ on $X$ generated by the open balls according to $d$. Meanwhile, many topologies are **not** induced by any metric (they are "non-metrizable"). For example, non-Hausdorff topologies are non-metrizable. We can in fact characterize the metrizable spaces, although it's a bit technical.

However, there's a crucial nuance here: different metrics on the same set can induce the same topology. For example, both the Euclidean metric $d_{Euc}((a,b),(c,d))=\sqrt{(a-c)^2+(b-d)^2}$ and the taxicab metric $d_{taxi}((a,b),(c,d))=\vert a-c\vert+\vert b-d\vert$ induce the same topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

So the passage from metric spaces to topological spaces is more complicated than just "pure generalization" (compare e.g. the passage from groups to monoids). We gain variety but lose specificity.